# MySQL JOIN with LIMIT query results

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, `products` and `origins`

Products:

```
p_id | name | origin_id 
------------------------
  1  |  P1  |    1
  2  |  P2  |    2
  3  |  P3  |    1
```

Origins:

```
o_id | name 
-------------
  1  |  O1  
  2  |  O2
```

I am using the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM `products` LEFT OUTER JOIN `origins` 
 ON ( `products`.`origin_id` = `origins`.`o_id` ) LIMIT 2
```

I am getting the below results

```
p_id | name | origin_id | o_id | name 
-----------------------------------------
  1  |  P1  |    1      |   1  |  O1  
  3  |  P3  |    1      |   1  |  O1
```

I was wondering how the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` affects the result where I am getting the first and the third row rather than the first and the second row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are not using `ORDER BY` Clause, there is no guarantee of a specific order for your `SELECT` query.

So we should use `ORDER BY` when we need any specific order.

See this: [MySQL Ref: What is The Default Sort Order of SELECT with no ORDER BY Clause](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,239471,239688#msg-239688)

Answer (score 1):

You don't control the inherent ordering of rows in a table.  It behaves like a set.  If you want to order it, use order by clause.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` p LEFT OUTER JOIN `origins` o
ON ( p.`origin_id` = o.`o_id` ) ORDER BY p.`name` LIMIT 2
```

Output :

```
p_id | name | origin_id | o_id | name 
-----------------------------------------
  1  |  P1  |    1      |   1  |  O1  
  2  |  P2  |    2      |   2  |  O2
```